# Weird Waveform and Histogram spazzout

Tags: interface, image, edit-mode

I was just wondering why these weird lines/gaps/spikes happen to waveform and histogram as soon as a modifier is used? Can something be done against this? [image: Weird spikes and lines]
And why is the Histogram in the preview so incredibly tiny and pixelated?

Comment: I'm not expert, but maybe interlaced video or similar feature that codec use for compresion - codec simply cut some of values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gaps are quantization gaps. If your image is deeper bit depth, you will have fewer gaps. Compare against a Cycles render at 32 bits float stored as an EXR versus say, an 8 bit TIFF.

Some 8 bit manipulations will squeeze values together or pull them apart, making the combing more obvious.

Comment: Other editing programs such as Davinci Resolve do not have these gaps, how is that? they create a smooth and easily readable histogram, waveform and vectorscope.

Comment: They are likely using a different rendering algorithm. Last I looked though, Resolve indeed shows combs with waveform parades. If you upload a 32 bit EXR I can take a look. Bottom line though is that 8 bit sources will be combed; there just isn't that dense of data in the files. Anything that shows a smooth vector-based output is lying to you.

Comment: I realized @KeenGaze that my last comment was likely a little too strong; lying is a poor term. What I strongly suspect is a division between analog trace lines and digital views are mixed. What is correct? Based on context I suppose. I'd prefer to see where the data falls, but some might prefer an agreement between an analog trace-line version and the comb version. Happy to try and trouble shoot at http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34814/the-rabbit-hole if you have any issues though.